# hexbin by matplotlib : get points in each hexagon?

Tags: python, matplotlib, binning

I am writting an app to interactively analyze 2D scatter plots with millions of points.
To reduce the number of points to plot and prevent reinventing the wheel, I use 2D hexagonal binning from matplotlib. (density plot)

The classical usage is:

```py
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

x=np.random.normal(loc=100,scale=20,size=100)
y=np.random.normal(loc=1000,scale=20,size=100)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 8))
hexbin = ax.hexbin(x, y, gridsize=25, cmap='jet',picker=True)
plt.show()
```

For my app, I need to know which points belong to each bin.

For this, I have two options:

- **use shapely** : extract the shape of each hexagon and use shapely to find whether the point is included or not . Here is my proof of concept (of course some optimisation can still be done to prevent testing points already allocated):

```py
import shapely

# get reference hexagon shape
paths = hexbin.get_paths()
hexagon_vertices = [item[0] for item in paths[0].iter_segments()]

# get offset to apply to each hexagon
list_offsets = hexbin.get_offsets()

list_points = [shapely.Point(x,y) for x,y in zip(x,y)]

list_idx = []
for offset in list_offsets:
    polygon = shapely.Polygon(shell = [corner + offset for corner in hexagon_vertices])
    is_in = polygon.contains(list_points)
    idx = np.argwhere(is_in==1).flatten()
    if len(idx)==0:
        idx = None
    list_idx.append(idx)
```

But I think this is an overkill as behind the scene, this info is already computed somehow by matplotlib. I had the look at the code of the hexbin function of matplotlib but I am a little bit lost...
The key part seems to be here:
https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/main/lib/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py#L5061-L5062
but I would need some help to be able to extract the usefull info...

- **adapt the matplotlib code** to extract this info : for this I would need some help :-)

I hope that someone will be able to help me.

Thanks a lot in advance,

Patrick

Comment: You don't need shapely. Anyway, that would be terribly slow. `hexbin` stores the bin centers, and you can calculate the distance from each point to each bin center, and keep the closest center.